# I2C library for Mono/C#

Tags: i2c, mono

Is there a library to use I2C bus on RPi for Mono/.NET?

I was trying to find anything, but there are only libraries to work with GPIO but not with I2C.

Comment: I do not think the Pi version of Linux supports it yet. Only bit banged. Hang on there... or get an external I2C to USB/Serial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long fruitless searching, I still didn't find anything on C#/Mono. So, I had to create my own library. In case someone else is looking for a similar solution, I put it on GitHub: https://github.com/mshmelev/RPi.I2C.Net

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about .Net libraries but have you looked into [overo-blinkm](https://github.com/scottellis/overo-blinkm)?

It was written for controlling an RGB LED. I am sure you can tweak it meet your requirements. It is written for the Gumstix board. I was able to cross compile it for the Raspberry Pi using the native makefile available in the library. I just had to change the I2C address to i2c-dev0

Comment: Thanks, it's a good place to start. But I wanted to have some out of the box solution :)

Comment: This [instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-I2C-Python/) also offers some perspective with respect to I2C. I am afraid you would be the first one to write one :)

Comment: The Pi4J library includes support for I2C communication

Comment: yep, and I wrote one.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one. I did a lot of testing, works well. MIT license. 
https://github.com/thomas3d/RPiCSIO

I have tested several other before, which had some problems.